# Windows 10 taskbar and start menu not loading

Tags: windows, windows-10, lenovo-laptop

I've upgraded to Windows 10 on my Lenovo Yoga 2. Last night, it made a loud whirring noise and turned off. When I turned it back on, it wouldn't let me click on the taskbar or start menu, it would just give me the loading cursor. The taskbar icons also do not load.

Sorry if this is the wrong forum for this type of issue.

Using startup repair or booting in safe mode did not solve anything and system restore failed

Comment: I suggest you try and refresh your system.  It sounds like you have massive system integrity issues.  If that is the case it is likely due to a failing HDD.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue however I had an alert stating that Cortana and my taskbar had failed. I came across another site that stated to try uninstalling my Anti Virus software specifically Avast. Apparently Avast and windows 10 clash. Not sure if this is your problem but maybe it will help.

> Do those dealing with this problem have avast antivirus installed? If so, I believe that is what is causing the 'critical error'. I uninstalled the software and upon reboot my start button and cortana were working perfectly again. Now I'm sure you all know how to uninstall software on your PCs but it may not work in normal mode with the critical error as it didn't with me. Therefore I uninstalled in safe mode. Incase you arent familiar with how to access safe mode on windows 10, heres how: You press ctrl+alt+delete, and in the bottom right hand corner you click the power button. Before you click 'restart', hold down the shift key until the next screen is displayed (blue). Then click troubleshoot, advanced options, start-up settings, restart. Once it restarts, press the F4 key, and when it restarts you will be in safe mode. Now just do the normal thing to uninstall avast and then reboot following the installation and it should be fixed!

Source: http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10/372745-windows-10-start-menu-cortana-not-working-fix-here-hopefully.html

Comment: Not using Avast, so that doesn't seem like the issue. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I solved it by turning on Avast's "Load Avast services only after loading other system services" option under its Settings -> Troubleshooting.