# Windows 10 Critical Error - Start Menu Not Working

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, start-menu, windows-error-reporting

After upgrading from windows 7 to 10 the main user on the laptop does not have any windows 10 application such as microsoft edge, cortana, etc. When I try to open the start menu or search, I get a critical error forcing me to sign out. There is no information in the event viewer and the only thing that worked was making a new account. In the new account I have the new apps and start menu, but I would like them to be on the old account. I'm not sure what information you need but I can give more information if requested. Thank you in advance.

Comment: the new startmenu sucks. Use the old Win7 Startmenu: http://superuser.com/a/946675/174557

Comment: Your not allowed to post software reccomendations.

Comment: I saw that forum already and considered it, but that would not fix the broken apps like settings and edge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 taskbar and start menu not loading](http://superuser.com/questions/962525/windows-10-taskbar-and-start-menu-not-loading)

Comment: @Mrfunny744 Questions that ask for software recommendations are unacceptable, but answers and comments mentioning third-party software are OK as long as they're not spam.

Answer (score 1):

I too have faced the same issue for 6 months or so,tried  many solutions that failed.

later after reading some issues, notes @MSDN i came to know that the issue is mainly with the users who have upgraded from 7/8/8.1 to windows 10.

The main cause for the issue is the "Internet explorer", the ui error occurs when windows tries to register both the browsers IE and Edge as OS built-in browsers.

so a simple solution for this issue is to disable "InternetExplorer",

- Perform a fresh boot into windows 10,
- Without doing anything else press "WIN + X" click on "programs and
  features"
- after opening click on "Turn Windows features on or off" on your
  left.
- once it opens up, un-check "Internet explorer 11" or whatever version
  is present there.
- and apply after that reboot your PC, some updates will be done.

Your start menu/cortana/UI hanging/error issue will be solved.

it worked out for me, hope it works out to you as well.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 options to this (according to my knowledge).

**Option 1:**

1. Go to run (Windows + r)
2. type regedit and press enter.
3. click ok when notification window prompt.
4. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER>Software>Microsoft>Windows>CurrentVersion>Explorer>Advanced
5. Create a Dword (32BIT) value by right clicking and selecting New > Dword (32bit) with the name ‘EnableXamlStartMenu’.
6. Give it value 0
7. Log off and login again.

Hopefully this fixes it.

**IF option 1 does not work, try option 2**

1. Right click on your start menu button.
2. click on search.
3. type power shell.
4. right click on power shell from search results.
5. click on run as administrator.
6. Execute below code :

`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}` **The " that are included are required**

Option 2 also fixes your issue with Microsoft Edge, Cortana, etc.

Hopefully one of the options worked for you!

Comment: I already tried option 2 on my main user account and in safe mode in my main user and it didn't work, I need to try on my new user account though. I will try these options and get back to you on whether or not it works.

Answer (score -1):

I was faced with this same issue after TH2 update. I tried many different approaches I found include attempting to create a new user. I couldn't even do that! So, in the end, I backed up everything and did a clean install.